# Symfony Return Type Declarations error when install WellCommerce

Tags: symfony, return-type, php-7, symfony-3.1

i install wellCommerce for symfony3 in my server with PHP7 and i'm getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException in AdminSubscriber.php line 74:
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'
```

The code that produce this error is this one:

```
private function getUserRepository() : UserRepositoryInterface
{
    return $this->get('user.repository');
}
```

I read about Return Type Declarations on php7 and i don't know why i'm getting this error.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed PHP5.6 and PHP7 but apache takes PHP5.6 as default. To fix this issue i remove all PHP in the server and install the last version of PHP7.1.

Comment: PHP 7.1 isn't stable yet, it might not be a good idea to use it for now.